Ktor SSL self signed certificate not working javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
I have followed official docs and example is not working for me on Debian.

keytool -keystore keystore.jks -alias sampleAlias -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -validity 3 -dname 'CN=localhost, OU=ktor, O=ktor, L=Unspecified, ST=Unspecified, C=US'

and application.conf
deployment {
    port = 3000
    sslPort = 8443
    host = "localhost"
}
ktor {
    security {
        ssl {
            keyStore = keystore.jks
            keyAlias = sampleAlias
            keyStorePassword = changeit
            privateKeyPassword = changeit
        }
    }
}

I am sure that configuration in application.conf is correct and that ktor on startup can see and access the store and certificate, because even if i change one of those values app wont start.
Problem is when i access from my browser https://localhost:8443 app gives
2024-05-20 23:22:53.899 [eventLoopGroupProxy-3-1] WARN  i.n.h.s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler - [id: 0xf6ca4b24, L:/127.0.0.1:8443 ! R:/127.0.0.1:33328] TLS handshake failed:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslEngine.unwrap(JdkSslEngine.java:92)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnSslEngine.unwrap(JdkAlpnSslEngine.java:163)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:297)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1353)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1246)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:296)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)

I have also tried exporting this certificate and adding it to main cacerts store but that did nothing. Also tried running intellij and all commands again as sudo, but that also did not change anything.
